# How do I make a Swift UIStackView size dynamically based on content?

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have added the following UIStackView to my ViewController. As the views change the values of textOneLabel and textTwoLabel change.

With the following code the initial StackView is centered and the portions filled proportionally. However with subsequent text combinations the bounds of the StackView don't change, leaving the content off center. How can I change the StackView properties so it will adapt to the content and always stay centered?

```
headerStackView.axis = .horizontal
headerStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
headerStackView.spacing = 8
headerStackView.layer.borderWidth = 1
headerStackView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    
headerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timerHeader.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
headerStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timerHeader.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
headerStackView.addArrangedSubview(textOneLabel)
headerStackView.addArrangedSubview(textTwoLabel)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're going for... Do you want the **space between the labels** to remain centered? Or do you want the **center of the stack view** to remain centered? That is, do you want it to look like the Top or Bottom examples here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qilC.png

Comment: Excellent example. I am trying to do your third option, where the stackView is centered in the view but the content on the right is longer than the content on the left. As noted above the initial view displays correctly, but when the words change, the stackView does not adapt to the new content size.

Comment: Let's try this again... do you want the **stackView FRAME** to remain centered? Or, do you want the **gap BETWEEN labels** to remain centered? https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEM36.png ... or, do you want something else? If so, show us an image of how you want it to look.

Comment: The StackView should always be centered in the view even if the content of the left and the content of the right are different length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forget you ever heard of `.fillProportionally`...

- it doesn't do what you think it does
- you'll encounter very unexpected layout issues if your stack view has spacing greater than Zero
- if your stack view has no width (neither width anchor nor leading/trailing anchors), `.fillProportionally` ***doesn't do anything***

So, change your `.distribution` to `.fill`.

Add these lines to control what auto-layout does with your labels:

```
    textOneLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    textOneLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    textTwoLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    textTwoLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

Now, your **stackView FRAME** will remain centered.

Comment: Thank you DonMag.